# Load, Change & Play Sound in BGE Without using Logic Bricks

Tags: scripting, game-engine, audio

Is it possible to load, manipulate (pitch-shift) and play back a sound without using logic bricks and instead using a script in Blender Game Engine?

Ideally, this would be possible with using only functionality included in Blender on Linux, Mac and Windows.

If this is not possible: what is the minimum required use of the logic bricks for this task?

Comment: you want to use a script ?

Comment: @Chebhou yes. I updated the question to make that clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need it to load a script file using an Always Sensor and a Python Controller. In the script file put:

```
import aud
device = aud.device()
sound = aud.Factory.file("sound.ogg")
sound = sound.pitch(2)
device.play(sound)
```

This will load the file, pitch-shift it and play it back.

[image: blend setup for script-based sound loading, editing and playback]